# I can't load web3. I keep getting this console error how do I fix it?

Tags: web3js, javascript

Error I keep getting is:
**app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
at app.js:1**

Code in my app.js:

```
const Web3 = require("web3");
const ethEnabled = async () => {
  if (window.ethereum) {
    await window.ethereum.send('eth_requestAccounts');
    window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Where do you run the code? Is it in a browser? Is it nodejs? We require more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use "require" in browser html file, you have to import it with  to use web3js client size.

If you want to "require" web3 on nodeJS first npm install web3 then require it on top of your server file.

Answer (score 0):

A) Create a file named apps.html

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
    const ethEnabled = async () => {
        if (window.ethereum) {
            let accounts = await window['ethereum'].request({method: 'eth_requestAccounts'});
            console.log('accounts:' + accounts);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
    ethEnabled().then((response) => {
        console.log(`Web3 available: ${response}`);
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

B) Start in the same folder a simple web server, e.g.:

```
python3 -m http.server
```

C) Now you can open the page in the web browser (with metamask).

```
http://localhost:8000/apps.html
```

D) Unlock metamask and connect one or more accounts to the page. Refresh the page in the browser. The console of your browser will show something like this:

```
accounts:0xbd004d9048c9b9e5c4b5109c68dd569a65c47cf9
Web3 available: true
```

Remarks:

1. To run in the browser your code needs a web server, static page will not work
2. The method 'send' is deprecated, so use 'request'
3. The code is tested with Chrome (version 120.0.6099.129) and Metamask on MacOS